# blender python, condition inside preset_values

Tags: python, scripting

I want to make a preset system for storing light parameters, like the light size, intensity and so on...

My issue is that there are parameters specific to each type of light like spotlights have `light.data.spot_size` .

How can i add a condition inside the preset_values array to check which type of light i am dealing with ?

Because otherwise if the parameter doesn't exist it will throw an error. Or maybe there's another method to handle this?

Here is the code:

```
class AddPresetObjectDisplay(AddPresetBase, bpy.types.Operator):
'''Save current parameters'''
bl_idname = "lighter.object_display_preset_add"
bl_label = "Save as a preset"
preset_menu = "OBJECT_MT_display_lighter_presets"
@classmethod
def poll(cls, context):             
     return True;

# variable used for all preset values
preset_defines = [
   "import json",
   "obj = bpy.context.active_object",
   "modifier = next(i for i in obj.modifiers if i.type == 'NODES')",
   "obj.data.update()",
   "light1 = bpy.data.objects['my-light0']"
]



# properties to store in the preset
preset_values = [

    
    "modifier['Input_6']",
    "light1.data.type",
#    Part where i want to add a condition
    "light1.data.shadow_soft_size"

    
   
]
```

Thanks

Comment: if you add a runnable script, i will have a look. But tbh i have no desire to stare at code fragments and guessing how it could work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.

```
class AddPresetObjectDisplay(AddPresetBase, bpy.types.Operator):
'''Save current parameters'''
bl_idname = "lighter.object_display_preset_add"
bl_label = "Save as a preset"
preset_menu = "OBJECT_MT_display_lighter_presets"
@classmethod
def poll(cls, context):             
     return True;

# variable used for all preset values
preset_defines = [
   "import json",
   "obj = bpy.context.active_object",
   "modifier = next(i for i in obj.modifiers if i.type == 'NODES')",
   "obj.data.update()",
   "light1 = bpy.data.objects['my-light0']"
]



# properties to store in the preset
@property
def preset_values(self):
  preset_values = [
    "modifier['Input_6']",
    "light1.data.type",
    "light1.data.shadow_soft_size"
    ]

  light1 = bpy.data.objects['my-light0']
  if light1.data.type == "SPOT":
      preset_values.append("light1.data.spot_size")
  return preset_values
```